# How do I get rid of the double scrollbar in my SPFX tab containing an iframe

Tags: html, reactjs, visual-c++, microsoft-teams, spfx

I am currently displaying a sharepoint webpage within an SPFX webpart that functions as a teams tab. The page displays incorrectly. Alot of white space gets stretched or white space gets added that isn't on the page I would like to display. The webpart also adds an extra scrollbar that I dont want, I suspect it's related to the white space. How do I remove the extra whitespace and remove the extra scrollbar. I added images to support your view of the problem. Here is my render function.

```
    public render(): React.ReactElement<ISpfxTabPageViewerProps> {
    return (
      <Iframe url= {this.state.siteName}
      height="100%"
      width="100%"/>
    );
  }
```

[Extra scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldGCt.png)
[Extra whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLt2t.png)

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue at our end. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab)?

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from comment for better understanding.

When you displaying a sharepoint webpage within an SPFX webpart that functions as a teams tab you will see only one scoll bar.please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab)?